# How to get the first letter of each word enter by user

Tags: prolog

**Here are the details of my code**

```
name:-read(X),write('Name : '),write(X),nameCode(X).
nameCode(X):-nl, write('Name Code : ').
```

**I would like to take the first 3 letters from each word and display it . What should be added to my code?
Furthermore, the result i get only allows me to enter a single name from user. When i attempt to enter several names(peter jane mary) in the query, it display a syntax message as below**

```
| ?- name.
|: peter jane mary.
* Syntax Error
```

**Below are the results of what i want to print**

```
Name : peter jane mary
Name Code : PJM
```

Answer (score 2):

1- First the user enters his/her first/middle/last name.

2- It is read.

3- **string_chars** breaks the string into characters : peter will become p,e,t,e,r

4- **getFirstLetter** Predicate extracts the first element from the list: from peter we get p.

5- **upcase_atom** convert lowercase letters to uppercase: p will become P.

6- display the answer using write.

```
 k:- 
  write('Enter First name: '),nl, 
  read(FName),nl, 
  string_chars(FName,N1),
  getFirstLetter(N1,L1),
  upcase_atom(L1,Str1),
  
    
  write('Enter Middle name: '),nl, 
  read(MName),nl, 
  string_chars(MName,N2),
  getFirstLetter(N2,L2),
  upcase_atom(L2,Str2),
  
    
  write('Enter Last name: '),nl, 
  read(LName),nl, 
  string_chars(LName,N3),
  getFirstLetter(N3,L3),
  upcase_atom(L3,Str3),
  write(Str1),write(' '),write(Str2),write(' '),write(Str3).  

 getFirstLetter([H|_],H).
```

**Example:**

```
?-k.

Enter First name:
peter

Enter Middle name:
jane

Enter Last name:
mary

P J M
```

___[image]

---

**A more challenging task: Remove the first letter from the name.**

1- First the user enters his/her first/middle/last name.

2- It is read.

3- **string_chars** breaks the string into characters : peter will become p,e,t,e,r

4- **removeFirstLetter** predicate removes the first letter: p,e,t,e,r will become e,t,e,r

5- **charstring** predicate will convert e,t,e,r to "e","t","e","r", we do this using **term_string** (this is important for the next
step)

6- **atomic_list_concat** joins all the separate charaters together: "e","t","e","r" will
become eter

```
 k:- 
      write('Enter first name: '),nl, 
      read(FName),nl, 
      string_chars(FName,N1),
      removeFirstLetter(N1,L1),
      charstring(L1,String1),
      atomic_list_concat( String1 , Cs1),
      
      write('Enter Middle name: '),nl, 
      read(MidName),nl,
      string_chars(MidName,N2),
      removeFirstLetter(N2,L2),
      charstring(L2,String2),
      atomic_list_concat( String2 , Cs2),
      
      write('Enter Last name: '),nl, 
      read(LName),nl,
      string_chars(LName,N3),
      removeFirstLetter(N3,L3),
      charstring(L3,String3),
      atomic_list_concat( String3 , Cs3),
      write(Cs1),write(" "),write(Cs2), write(" "),write(Cs3).
        
charstring([],[]).
    charstring([H|T],[H2|L]):-
    term_string(H,H2),
charstring(T,L).
    
removeFirstLetter([_|T],T).
```

**Example:**

```
?-k.

Enter first name:
peter

Enter Middle name:
jane

Enter Last name:
mary

eter ane ary
1true
```

Comment: i tried several times but it shows error like this 
`| ?- k.
Enter First name: 
|: peter.

! ----------------------------------------
! Error 23 : Type Error
! Goal     : strbyt(peter,_3434).`

Comment: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/name1,pl.pl  click on the link and check it.

Comment: @EddieJn check the image I added in the answer.

Comment: I think this happens because I'm using LPA prolog. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: You are repeating your code a lot. Smaller predicates will make the code more clear.   https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/getinitials.pl

Comment: @rajashekar nice :)

Answer (score 1):

The built-in predicate read/1 reads in a prolog term, terminated by a full-stop.
"peter jane mary" is not a prolog term, so you get a syntax error. In particular, prolog doesn't know what to do with the blank space between your names.

If you prefer to use comma to separate names, you can get this:

```
?- read(X), X = ','(A, ','(B,C)).
|: peter,mary,paul.

X =  (peter,mary,paul),
A = peter,
B = mary,
C = paul.
```

The comma is interpreted as a functor (in standard prolog).
Have I replied your question ?